# Creating an Apps Script function that takes other functions as arguments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a function in APPSCRIPT that takes as argument another APPSCRIPT function.

I tried this:

```
function mainFunction(spreadsheetRange, secondaryFunction) {
  
  // values = array of values retrieved from range
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i = i+1) {
    values[i] = secondaryFunction(values[i]);
  }

  // update the range with the new values
}


function function1() {
  //something
}

function function2() {
  //something
}
```

and running (after importing all these functions) in a google sheet cell the following formula:
`=mainFunction(validrange, function2)`

But this error appears:
`TypeError: fun is not a function`.

The same happens with`=mainFunction(validrange, function2())`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share more details on your implementation? The script shared does not have a fun function.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, the following modified script is your expected result?

#### Modified script:

```js
function mainFunction(spreadsheetRange, secondaryFunction) {
  
  // values = array of values retrieved from range
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i = i+1) {
    values[i] = this[secondaryFunction](values[i]); // <--- Modified
  }

  // update the range with the new values
}
```

- In this modification, for example, when you put `=mainFunction(validrange, "function2")` to a cell, the function `function2` is used with `values[i] = this[secondaryFunction](values[i])`.

  - But when I saw your function of `function2`, no arguments are used. So, in this case, `values[i]` is not given to `function2`. Please be careful about this.
- In this case, please use `"function2"` of `=mainFunction(validrange, "function2")` as the text value. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem to pass a function as an argument:

```
function main() {

  function mainFunction(func, arg) {
      return func(arg);
  }

  function function1(num) { return num * 2 }

  function function2(num) { return num * 3 }

  var value = mainFunction(function1, 2);
  console.log(value) // output ---> 4

  var value = mainFunction(function2, 2);
  console.log(value) // output ---> 6

}
```

You can try it right here:

```js
function mainFunction(func, arg) {
    return func(arg);
}

function function1(num) { return num * 2 }

function function2(num) { return num * 3 }

var value = mainFunction(function1, 2);
console.log(value) // output 4

var value = mainFunction(function2, 2);
console.log(value) // output 6
```